# Loop of mutate functions over columns in R

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

I am trying to create a loop function from several mutate (dplyr package) functions. Each code line below works perfectly, but I am looking for something more elegant (in one line of code, if possible) because I'd need to repeat these five lines 10 more times (for ten additional data frames).

`ism.50` is my data.frame with 5 columns and 10,000 rows.

```r
Isim_n20<dbl> Isim_n30<dbl> Isim_n50<dbl> Isim_n100<dbl> Isim_n1000<dbl>
1   1.7789999   3.7416683   1.8228680   1.1573671   1.0336168
2   1.3475063   0.7559132   1.2948982   0.9957275   0.9409909
3   0.5980781   1.7888836   1.4068773   1.0847899   0.9354231
4   1.4656961   1.6271786   1.2401491   1.1348101   0.9749408
5   1.8969097   0.6829495   1.4543307   0.8554704   1.0039841
6   1.3969583   1.1180521   0.7765212   0.8293486   1.0257257
7   0.9155140   1.3892062   0.8045851   1.0480486   1.0344771
```

`breaks` is  vector `breaks = c(0,0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1, 1.2, 1.4, Inf)`

`labels` is a vector `labels = c("(0:0.6]", "(0.6:0.7]", "(0.7:0.8]", "(0.8:0.9]", "(0.9:1]", "(1:1.2]", "(1.2:1.4]", ">1.4")`

```
ism.50 <- ism.50 %>% mutate(Intv_n20=cut(ism.50[,1], breaks=breaks, labels=labels))
ism.50 <- ism.50 %>% mutate(Intv_n30=cut(ism.50[,2], breaks=breaks, labels=labels)) 
ism.50 <- ism.50 %>% mutate(Intv_n50=cut(ism.50[,3], breaks=breaks, labels=labels)) 
ism.50 <- ism.50 %>% mutate(Intv_n100=cut(ism.50[,4], breaks=breaks, labels=labels)) 
ism.50 <- ism.50 %>% mutate(Intv_n1000=cut(ism.50[,5], breaks=breaks, labels=labels))
```

I tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
for (j in 1:col(ism.50)) {
  ism.50 %>% mutate(Intv_[j]=cut(ism.50[j], breaks=breaks, labels=labels))
}
```

Comment: Can you show an example of `ism.50`? Perhaps by using `dput(ism.50)`>

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out, the `across` function is new but it helps with renaming. Let me know if you need me to tweak it. The nice thing about this is it is scaleable. so if you have 100 columns it would be fine.

```
 library(tidyverse)
    mutate(ism.50,
          across(starts_with("Isim"), 
          ~cut(., 
               breaks = breaks,
               labels = labels), 
          .names = "replace{col}")) %>% 
          rename_at(vars(starts_with("replace")), ~str_replace(., "replaceIsim", "Intv"))
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but when I try to run the code it gives me this error message ```Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`. x object '.' not found ℹ Input `..1` is `across(...)`.```

Comment: Sorry about that, they are using glue as part of the naming function which didn't throw an error in my test case. I made a tibble of your data and reran it. I editted the code

Comment: It works perfectly @NotThatKindODr, thank! This saves me a lot of headaches!

Comment: Happy to help!!